# OpenGL program works on AMD but not on NVIDIA

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia

And the error is "Access violation reading location in nvoglv64.dll"
[image: Error Message]
[image: Console Log]
The program worked as intended on my old AMD Radeon HD 6970. A few days ago I bought a GTX 970. Great card, but I would like my program to work. I want to render a quad to the screen for deferred rendering. I try to use OpenGL 4.4
Source:

Preparing the quad:

```
modelMatrix = mat4(1.0);

vertices.push_back(vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
vertices.push_back(vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
vertices.push_back(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

vertices.push_back(vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
vertices.push_back(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
vertices.push_back(vec3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

normals.push_back(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
normals.push_back(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
normals.push_back(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

normals.push_back(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
normals.push_back(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
normals.push_back(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

indices.push_back(0);
indices.push_back(1);
indices.push_back(2);

indices.push_back(0);
indices.push_back(2);
indices.push_back(3);

uvs.push_back(vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
uvs.push_back(vec2(1.0f, 0.0f));
uvs.push_back(vec2(1.0f, 1.0f));

uvs.push_back(vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
uvs.push_back(vec2(1.0f, 1.0f));
uvs.push_back(vec2(0.0f, 1.0f));

indexCount = static_cast<int>(indices.size());
is2D = true;

unsigned int handle[2];
glGenBuffers(2, handle);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &array2D);
glBindVertexArray(array2D);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((GLubyte *)NULL + (0)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Vertex position

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((GLubyte *)NULL + (0)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // Texture coordinates

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Rendering the quad:

```
// The following three lines are called in the render loop (as 2nd pass).
// I skip rendering meshes in the first pass to better understand this error.
//sp->useSubRoutine(srp2); // SP is the shader program
//sp->resetMatrices(); // Set matrices to mat4(1.0);
//dq->render(); // DQ is the display quad


glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); // fbo is 0 for quad
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

if (shader != nullptr)
{
    shader->use();
    shader->setModelMatrix(modelMatrix);
}

if (is2D)
{
    glBindVertexArray(array2D);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indexCount); // ERROR HERE
    return;
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 440

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexNormal;

centroid out vec2 UV;
out vec4 position;
out vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 uniMatModel;
uniform mat4 uniMatView;
uniform mat4 uniMatProjection;
uniform mat4 uniMatModelView;
uniform mat4 uniMatModelViewProjection;
uniform mat3 uniMatNormal;




void main()
{
    UV = vertexUV;
    position = uniMatModelView * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    normal = normalize(uniMatNormal * vertexNormal);
    gl_Position = uniMatModelViewProjection * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 440

struct lightInfo {
    vec4 position;
    vec3 intensity;
    bool isActive;
};


// IN
centroid in vec2 UV;
in vec4 position;
in vec3 normal;


// OUT
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 positionData;
layout (location = 2) out vec3 normalData;
layout (location = 3) out vec3 colorData;


// SUBROUTINES
subroutine void renderPassType();
subroutine uniform renderPassType renderPass;


// UNIFORMS
uniform sampler2D uniSamTexture;
uniform sampler2D uniSamAlpha;
uniform sampler2D uniSamAmbient;
uniform sampler2D uniSamSpecular;
uniform sampler2D uniSamShininess;

uniform lightInfo uniPointLights[32];
uniform vec3 uniVec3AmbientEmissiveness;

layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D positionTex;
layout(binding=1) uniform sampler2D normalTex;
layout(binding=2) uniform sampler2D colorTex;

subroutine (renderPassType)
void renderWorld()
{
    if (texture2D(uniSamAlpha, UV).rgb[0] == 1.0) // Alphamaps have to be inverted
    {
        discard;
    }
    else
    {
        colorData = texture2D(uniSamTexture, UV).rgb;
    }

    positionData = vec3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    normalData = normal;
    fragColor = vec4(colorData, 1.0);
}

subroutine (renderPassType)
void renderLight()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); // For testing purposes set to red
}

void main()
{
    renderPass();
}
```

Comment: Have you pressed the break-button in the error-message? Which line causes the error?

Comment: Yes, I have done a lot of breaking and debugging line-by-line since this was not the only problem. The error line is marked with `// ERROR HERE`. It's in the rendering part :)

Comment: Sorry. I simply overread the comment :). See my answer below for some possible problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such problems can occure on NVIDIA cards when you try to read from a vertex buffer that does not have enough elements in it. For example rendering 9 vertices from a buffer that only contains 6. AMD interestingly does not complain about that.

In your case you bind a vertex buffer to attribute location 2, but you activate location 1. This:

```
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((GLubyte *)NULL + (0)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // Texture coordinates
```

should actually be

```
                              ||
                              \/ 
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((GLubyte *)NULL + (0)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // Texture coordinates
```

Edit:
I just saw another thing

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

uvs.size() equals 6 in your application, so OpenGL will try to read 6 * 3 = 18 float. Your uvs-array  only contains 12 floats (since you are using vec2 here).

Comment: Just for curiosity: Which of the two problems caused the exception?

Comment: oooohh, I really did not see that error! That's why it is important to talk to people when you have a problem^^ Finally it renders.